# Jewels and Stones

Tags: javascript, algorithm, programming-challenge, ecmascript-6

**The task**

is taken from [leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/jewels-and-stones/)

> You're given strings J representing the types of stones that are
>   jewels, and S representing the stones you have.  Each character in S
>   is a type of stone you have.  You want to know how many of the stones
>   you have are also jewels.
>
> The letters in J are guaranteed distinct, and all characters in J and
>   S are letters. Letters are case sensitive, so "a" is considered a
>   different type of stone from "A".
>
> **Example 1:**
>
> Input: J = "aA", S = "aAAbbbb"
>
> Output: 3
>
> **Example 2:**
>
> Input: J = "z", S = "ZZ"
>
> Output: 0
>
> Note:
>
> S and J will consist of letters and have length at most 50. The
>   characters in J are distinct.

**My functional solution**

```
/**
 * @param {string} J
 * @param {string} S
 * @return {number}
 */
var numJewelsInStones = function(J, S) {
  const set = new Set(J);
  return [...S].reduce((ac, s) => set.has(s) + ac, 0);
};
```

**My imperative solution:**

```
/**
 * @param {string} J
 * @param {string} S
 * @return {number}
 */
var numJewelsInStones = function(J, S) {
  let num = 0;
  const set = {};
  for (let j = 0; j < J.length; j++) {
    set[J[j]] = 1;
  }
  for (let s = 0; s < S.length; s++) {
    num += set[S[s]] || 0;
  }
  return num;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is concise and readable... I didn't have any feedback... it really shows how the functional solution is nicer.

I was curious if it could be done with regular expressions and no iteration, so I played around and got:

```
const numJewelsInStones = (j,s) => { 
  const m = s.match(new RegExp(`[${j}]`,'g'))
  return m ? m.length : 0 
}
```

or even

```
numJewelsInStones = (j,s) => s.replace(new RegExp(`[^${j}]`,'g'),'').length
```

Comment: Very clever indeed

Answer (score 1):

Instead of populating a `Set` and using `.has()`, you can use [String includes()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes.asp) directly. After that, it's just a matter of filtering the array and taking its length. I'd avoid using regexes unless they actually simplify things.

```js
const countJewels = (J, S) => [...S].filter(n => J.includes(n)).length

console.log(countJewels("aA", "aAaabb"))
```

Your functions should be `const` unless you intend to change them. I wouldn't use parameter names like `J` and `S`, but I guess those were given by leetcode.

Comment: Includes is slower I think

Comment: For length 50 it might actually not be. Anyway, the inputs are so short you don't need to care.

Answer (score 0):

here is my proposal: there are fewer cycles, and uses a regex more "simple" for interpreters javascript (I think that the use of the Set consumes more resources)

```js
function numJewelsInStones(J, S)
{
  return [...J].reduce((ac, j) => ac + (S.match(RegExp(j)) || []).length, 0)
}

console.log( "'aA', 'aAAbbbb' ==>", numJewelsInStones('aA', 'aAAbbbb') )
console.log( "'z', 'ZZ' ==>", numJewelsInStones('z', 'ZZ') )
```